# How can I position an input inside and into the bottom of an iframe?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
    <iframe runat="server" id="iFrameMap">
    </iframe>
    <input type="button" runat="server" onclick="return false;" id="btnRedirect" class="button ttButton ttAjaxStateChange ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Open View" />
</div>
```

I would like to position my input tag to be at the bottom of the iframe, the whole of the input tag being inside the iframe, even though structurally it is outside the iframe. Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add `position:relative` to the containing `<div>`, then put `position:absolute;bottom:0` on the `<input/>`.